# ADF same code different processing depending on environment

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'd like to delete files in the dev data lake and archive them to long term storage in the production environment.  How would I check what environment I'm running ADFv2 in so that I can switch/branch depending on environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a pipeline with an IF activity that checks for either the data factory name or you could set a global parameter called pENV which would be set to "DEV" or "PROD" based on the environment.

In the IF activity, check the value of the global parameter and either go to the execution path with the delete activity or the path with your archive logic